# Is it possible to get all Linkedin Profile Posts with Linkedin Api

Tags: linkedin-api, feed, posts

I am trying to use linkedin API for showing the feeds of my profile what i have posted from the day first. posts include media, images, video etc. I would like to know is there any Api available for that where i can pass some parameter and get all posts of my linkedin Profile. Please help if anyone have done this before

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

You can [Retrieve Shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#retrieve-shares) with the api using the person id:

```
curl  -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer token<>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:person:{id}'
```

You can retrieve the person id with the [Retrieve Authenticated Member's Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/marketing/context#usage) API

```
 curl  -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <token>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)'
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Matteo I can retrieve my profile ID using `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)` . But trying to retrieve posts returns `403 - Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares`.

Comment: See the permission section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#permissions probably you need to ask for extended permission for you app

Comment: to access pull type of information ( pull likes, posts, comments  ) of a user , you need " r_member_social " permission , which you can only get after applying to Linkedin marketing developer program. Post applying for his, you may or may not be approved by Linkedin for this permission.

Comment: Hi from 2023. They are shutting down this API today. Do you know what alternative are we supposed to use?

Comment: @fombo, I've got response that hints about the API is healthy but requires request header preset with token

`{"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}`

Comment: Any site for end-users which allows us to do the same?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the official linkedin api documentation to get all your posts id , then using that you can retrieve more information. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?tabs=http