# Linkedin v2 API - reading company posts with PHP

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Our POST query is:

```
$urn = "urn:li:organization:$company_id";
$post_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/$urn?viewContext=AUTHOR&oauth2_access_token=" .$accessToken;
```

But it always gives an error:

> {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access:
>   POST /ugcPosts/urn:li:organization:18880318","status":403}

What can be done to get past that error?

Comment: Have you already see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54627787/2270041

Comment: Does it work with company as well?

Comment: Yes, simply use the organization urn