# How to retrieve Linkedin page posts using its API in 2023

Tags: linkedin-api

I have to embed the posts feed of a company on its website. I was going to use the API as it is mentioned here: [Is it possible to get all Linkedin Profile Posts with Linkedin Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625971/is-it-possible-to-get-all-linkedin-profile-posts-with-linkedin-api)

However, I found out that they are shutting down this API today.
[image]
What alternative are we suposed to use?

Answer (score 1):

The [Posts API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-02&tabs=http) is replacing the Shares API. Documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares?view=li-lms-2023-02#posts-api).

Comment: Doesn't using this API to embed a feed in a website violate the Marketing API terms, as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/restricted-use-cases?view=li-lms-2023-02 ?